# how to make updated_at the only column updating and not created_at

Tags: mysql, laravel

Every time I am updating a data in MYSQL, the created_at updates the same time as updated_at. I only want updated_at to be the only ones to be updating. is there anyway I can do this?

Laravel 4.2 - 5.1

here is my code in controller

```
public function read(){
        $response = array();

        $data = Docs::find(Input::get("id"));



        if($data){

            $data -> read = "1";

            $data -> save();

            $response["success"] = TRUE;

        }

        return Response::json($response);

    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you use to update the data? Sounds like you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: Looks like your table, in the database, is a table who has the setting to to be a timestamp which updates on update.

Comment: Woops, ment column, your created_at column might be setup to automatically update when the table data updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is nothing wrong with your code, it might be a problem with how the database was setup.

A common mistake is that the created_at column, in the database, is setup to be a timestamp that automatically updates when the table data changes.